# Can I not do System.out.println(Item.toString());?

Tags: java, string, printing

I have overridden class Object's `toString` method, but mine is not working, and I can't figure out why.  Here is the code on my method (in a class called `ShoppingBag`):

```
public String toString(){ 
    String str = ""; 
    Item temp = record;  
    str += "\n\nThe bag contains:\n"; 
    str += String.format("%-18s%-13s%-12s\n", "Name of the Items", "Quantity", "Subtotal"); 
    while(temp != null){ 
        str += String.format("%-18s%-13s%-12s\n", temp.getItemName(), temp.getQuantity(),
           "$"+(temp.getRetailPrice()*temp.getQuantity()));
    }
    str += String.format("%-18s%-13s%-12s\n", "", "Total:", "$"+this.totalCost()); 
    str += String.format("%-18s%-13s%-12s\n", "", "Tax(5%):", "$"+(this.totalCost()
          * taxRate)); 
    str += String.format("%-18s%-13s%-12s\n", "", "Grand Total:", "$"+this.totalCost()
          +(this.totalCost()*taxRate)); 
    String test = "test1";
    return test;
}
```

I know that there's a lot of junk in there with a class Item and String.format. There are no exceptions when I compile or run, it just doesn't print anything.

In my application, I try this:

```
ShoppingBag bag = new ShoppingBag(parameters);
System.out.println(bag.toString());
```

and nothing prints.  When I comment out everything but the final two lines of my method (`String test = "test1"; return test;`) it prints "test1", but that other block of text shouldn't affect the test variable, so I don't understand why it won't print otherwise.

Comment: When is `temp` ever `null`?

Comment: You are misusing `toString()`. The method is mainly for developer use when debugging. It is not for printing the content of the shopping bag to a user. For that you should have a `print` method which takes a `PrintWriter` as a parameter. That way the writer might be able to stream the output straight to the destination (file or network client). The `toString()` method should be short and concise, with just enough summary information to distinguish multiple bags when debugging.

Comment: Always show the code that doesn't work. How do we know that you actually return `str` in your non-functioning code? You'd be surprised how often silly bugs like that happen.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing prints because you are stuck in an infinite loop; this one:

```
while(temp != null){ 
    str += String.format("%-18s%-13s%-12s\n", temp.getItemName(), temp.getQuantity(), "$"+(temp.getRetailPrice()*temp.getQuantity()));
}
```

`temp` is never `null` so you never break out of that loop.

That's why when you remove those lines, it starts to work (you remove the infinite loop). You should remove that `while` loop. You probably meant for it to be an `if` statement instead (to avoid `NullPointerException`). To recap, you probably meant `if (temp != null)` instead of `while (temp != null)` ([tutorial on `while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) statement, [tutorial on `if`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) statement).

Also, consider using [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of all the String concatenations.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, I forgot 1 line:

    temp = temp.getLink();    This assigns temp to the next variable in the LinkedList.